# Reference PHP file with AJAX from a Vue dev project

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vue.js, axios

I've used [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to build a Vue project. One of its `package.json` scripts is

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
```

and I use this to develop my project. The problem is when I want to reference a PHP file in an AJAX call from a Vue component, it returns a `404` error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a way to reference PHP files during development?

Comment: have you tried to GET http://localhost/test.php ? I hope you run locally server which runs PHP.

Comment: That produces the same error.

Comment: what web server you run?

Comment: You'll need to open up the php server, `webpack-dev-server` will not serve php files: `php -S localhost:8000` you can then access your file at: http://localhost:8000/test.php

Comment: Yes of course, thank you. My new problem is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`..

Comment: You will need to serve your pages from the `php` server, not via `webpack-dev-server`. Honestly, getting HMR to work with webpack and php is awkward. I use `browserify-hmr` with `gulp` to watch for file changes in development and webpack for production, because webpacks `hmr` refreshes the webpack-dev-server not the php server, whereas `browserify-hmr` (which uses the webpack api) will reload the `php` server.

Comment: It's a small project so I'm taking the nightmarishly-awkward route and re-building the code until I've finished working on the AJAX part of it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution would be adding header 1st then run the php file as shown below.

```
//it should be the 1st line in the php code.
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Then run this file 1st.

```
php -S localhost:8888 phpfile.php
```

Then you can access the php output with axios.get(localhost:8888/phpfile.php).

But this is a temporary solution because I am stuck here, if i want to manage different php outputs to a page. Then i have to run all those files in different servers and then use them in the axios.get.
Please help me if anyone know how to access the php file without running any services. 
Thanks